# Python multi-line regex

Tags: python, regex, pdf

I am using [pdfplumber.page.extract_text()](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) to extract text from bank statements. The text seems to get extracted correctly but I am having trouble with the regex expression to extract the date, type, description and amount.  but I cant figure out a clean way to capture multi-line descriptions. I would like to have the description text in the gold boxes grouped with the description text in the line before the gold box.

### Regex Pattern

`re.findall(r'(\d{2}\/\d{2})\s*([\w ]*)([$\d.,]*)(\s{2})([$\d.,]*).*\s(?=\w*)', text)`

### Regex Description

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}) - Capture date
([\w ]*) - Capture description
([$\d.,]*) - Capture expense amount
([$\d.,]*) - Capture deposit amount
(?=\w*) - Positive Lookahead for any text below
```

### Input

```
  0  0  $12,345.67 
08/27  DEBIT CARD PURCHASE XXXXXX 5541XXXXXX  $1.23  0  $123,456.78
RACETRAC467 00004671 PLEASANTVILLEPA
08/27  BANK FUNDS TRANSFER DB  $45.67  0  $124,816.32
TO SMITH,JOHN
SAVINGS #0001, CONF# 8675309
continued on next page>>>
 987654-3210
Page 1 of 11
```

### Current Output

```
['08/27', 'DEBIT CARD PURCHASE XXXXXX 5541XXXXXX  ', '$1.23', '  ', '0', '  $123,456.78 ']
['08/27', 'BANK FUNDS TRANSFER DB  ', '$45.67', '  ', '0', '  $124,816.32 ']
```

### Desired Output

```
['08/27', 'DEBIT CARD PURCHASE XXXXXX 5541XXXXXX RACETRAC467 00004671 PLEASANTVILLEPA  ', '$1.23', '  ', '0', '  $123,456.78 ']
['08/27', 'BANK FUNDS TRANSFER DB TO SMITH,JOHN SAVINGS #0001, CONF# 8675309 ', '$45.67', '  ', '0', ' $124,816.32 ']
```

Comment: Please post the input text and read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the description of the following lines (that for example do not start with a date or 'continued" or Page and a digit) to the description that you already have.

In your pattern you use `[\w ]*` but that can also only match spaces. If there should be at least a word character you can use `\w[\w ]*`

You can also omit the capture group in this part `(\s{2})` as it will return an entry with spaces only.

```
(?P<date>\d{2}/\d{2})\s+(?P<desc>\w[\w ]*)(?P<expense>\$[\d.,]*)\s{2}(?P<deposit>\d[\d.,]*)\s.*(?P<desc_more>(?:\n(?!\d+\/\d|continued\b|Page\s+\d).*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?P<date>\d{2}/\d{2})` Group *date*
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?P<desc>\w[\w ]*)` Group *desc* match word chars and spaces
- `(?P<expense>\$[\d.,]*)` Group *expense* Match `$` and optional digits `.` or `,`
- `\s{2}` Match 2 whitespace chars
- `(?P<deposit>\d[\d.,]*)` Group *deposit* Match a digits and optional digits `.` or `,`
- `\s.*` Match a single whitespace char and the rest of the line
- `(?P<desc_more>` Group *desc_more*

  - `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

    - `\n(?!\d+\/\d|continued\b|Page\s+\d).*` Match a newline, and the rest of the line if it does not start with a date like pattern or any of the other alternatives
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `)` Close group *desc_more*

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCDq7d/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5qIc0d).

An example using named capture groups and the `match.groupdict()`:

```
import re

pattern = r"(?P<date>\d{2}/\d{2})\s+(?P<desc>\w[\w ]*)(?P<expense>\$[\d.,]*)\s{2}(?P<deposit>\d[\d.,]*)\s.*(?P<desc_more>(?:\n(?!\d+\/\d|continued\b|Page\s+\d).*)*)"

s = ("  0  0  $12,345.67 \n"
     "08/27  DEBIT CARD PURCHASE XXXXXX 5541XXXXXX  $1.23  0  $123,456.78\n"
     "RACETRAC467 00004671 PLEASANTVILLEPA\n"
     "08/27  BANK FUNDS TRANSFER DB  $45.67  0  $124,816.32\n"
     "TO SMITH,JOHN\n"
     "SAVINGS #0001, CONF# 8675309\n"
     "continued on next page>>>\n"
     " 987654-3210\n"
     "Page 1 of 11\n"
     "07/27  DEBIT CARD PURCHASE XXXXXX 6541XXXXXX  $2.23  0  $223,456.78")

matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)

for _, match in enumerate(matches):
    d = match.groupdict()
    d.update({'desc': re.sub(r"[^\S\n]*\n", " " , match.groupdict().get('desc') + match.groupdict().get('desc_more'))})
    del d["desc_more"]
    print(d)
```

Output

```
{'date': '08/27', 'desc': 'DEBIT CARD PURCHASE XXXXXX 5541XXXXXX RACETRAC467 00004671 PLEASANTVILLEPA', 'expense': '$1.23', 'deposit': '0'}
{'date': '08/27', 'desc': 'BANK FUNDS TRANSFER DB TO SMITH,JOHN SAVINGS #0001, CONF# 8675309', 'expense': '$45.67', 'deposit': '0'}
{'date': '07/27', 'desc': 'DEBIT CARD PURCHASE XXXXXX 6541XXXXXX  ', 'expense': '$2.23', 'deposit': '0'}
```

Comment: I ended up slightly modifying the regex you provided for a different part of code but I dont see how its messing up. I'm using `(?P<date>\d+\/\d+)\s+(?P<desc>\w[\w ]*)(?P<expense>[\d.]*)\s+(?P<deposit>\d[\d.]*)\s.*(?P<desc_more>(?:\n(?!\d+\/\d+).*)*)` but a couple of lines are not being captured and its not obvious why its not working. https://regex101.com/r/tyxkTU/1

Comment: @JohnR But that is a different data format, and the deposit does not seem to be there. Perhaps a pattern like this can help you further https://regex101.com/r/ouJrw6/1

Comment: Ahh! I see... I didnt realize I could use multiple lookahead! Thanks